# Recurring Stripe Payments and Invoices

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm currently creating a donation form that allows users to enter in the amount they would like to donate (Variable amounts) and charge them monthly on a recurring basis. I'm found 2 ways to do this"

**Option 1**

1. Create the customer
2. Subscribe the customer to a subscription plan that costs $0.00
3. Charge the customer the variable amount
4. Create an invoice

   ```
      $customer = Customer::create(array(
                   "card" => $_POST['stripe_token'],
                   "description" => "Monthly Donation",
                   "email" => $_POST['email'],
                   "metadata" => array("email" => $_POST['email']),
                   ));  

       $subscription = Subscription::create(array(
                                  "customer" => $customer->id,
                                  "items" => array(array('plan' => '004')),
                                  ));

      $charge = Charge::create(array(
                                   "amount" => $_POST['amount'],
                                   "currency" => "usd",
                                   "customer" => $customer['id'],
                                   "description" => "Monthly Donation",
                                   "metadata" => array("email" => $_POST['email']),
                                   "receipt_email" => $_POST['email'],
                                  )); 


       $invoice = InvoiceItem::create(array("amount" => $_POST['amount'],
                                   "currency" => "usd",
                                   "customer" => $customer['id'],
                                   "description" => "Monthly Donation",
                                   ));
   ```

This actually works pretty well except the Invoice that gets sent to the customer the following month. Contains the price and name of the invoice as $0.00, then the monthly donation associated.

Is there a way to remove the $0.00 and subscription name?

Here is an image of the invoice so you can understand better:
[image]

**Option 2:**

1. Create the customer
2. Create a product (Monthly donation)
3. Create a plan
4. Charge the customer the variable amount
5. Create an invoice

   ```
   $customer = Customer::create(array(
       "card" => $_POST['stripe_token'],
       "description" => "VA Monthly Donation",
       "email" => $_POST['email'],
       "metadata" => array("email" => $_POST['email']),
   ));

   $product = Product::create(array(
       "name" => "PR Monthly Donation",
       "type" => "service",
   ));

   $plan = Plan::create(array(
       "currency" => "usd",
       "interval" => "month",
       "product" => array("name" => "Monthly Donation"),
       "id" => "005",
       "amount" => $_POST['amount'],
   ));

   $charge = Charge::create(array(
       "amount" => $_POST['amount'],
       "currency" => "usd",
       "customer" => $customer['id'],
       "description" => "Monthly Donation",
       "metadata" => array("email" => $_POST['email']),
       "receipt_email" => $_POST['email'],
   ));

   $invoice = InvoiceItem::create(array("amount" => $_POST['amount'],
       "currency" => "usd",
       "customer" => $customer['id'],
       "description" => "Monthly Donation",
   ));
   ```

The invoice turns out great on this, just what I want in Option 1:
[image]
But the negative is, this creates a new subscription plan for each customer.
I would end up with hundreds of subscription plans, which is not very clean.
[image]

**So I definitely like option 1 the best, but need a way to clean up that invoice if possible. Is there a way to remove the $0.00 and subscription name from the invoice in option 1? Or make the invoice in option 1 look like the invoice in option 2?**

If anyone has a better method I would be open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Another option to consider would be to set the subscription cost to $0.01 and then set the quantity appropriately for each user to get to the desired amount.

Comment: Customer get's charged the entered amount each month or is the customer able to change the amount monthly?

Comment: @PatrickQ Not a bad idea at all. I believe I saw that option somewhere. But would the recurring invoice then say. John Doe subscribed to "Monthly Donations" x 1000 on a $100 dollar a month donation? I'll have to try that out. Would I simply add `"quantity" => $_POST['amount'],` under subscriptions?

Comment: @Kisaragi Customer get's charged the entered amount each month. Although thinking about it more, I would like the user to be able to pause the subscription / resume if needed. So maybe option 2 is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I was under the impression that having multiple plans is expected due to having hundreds of them, though it is messy in the dashboard.

Comment: I think @PatrickQ idea will be the best way to go.  As my original question asks, is there any way to change the look on the Stripe invoice though? This is very clumsy looking: `$28.00  |  2,800 × Subscription to Recurring ($0.01 / month)`  If not, I guess rather having Stripe send the receipts I will create a custom email receipt, and do the same for reminders of upcoming payments / invoices.

Comment: I got the same issue recently. Option 2 seems more secure.